# npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump

Tags: angular, npm

> npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a
>   major version bump
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Al crear un proyecto angular con ng new proyecto, me aparecen los WARN? ya intente actualiza el Node, AngularCli y NPM, pero sigue dando el mismo mensaje. Mi configuracion es:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```